# In Pathfinder, does the summoner or the GM control the eidolon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoning, summoner

I'm starting up a summoner character in a Pathfinder campaign, but we're a little unsure of the rules for eidolons. While I know the summoner is the one who tells her eidolon what to do, I'm wondering whether the player or the GM decides what the eidolon actually does.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no fixed rule for this, so it will be up to you and your GM to work this out.

An Eidolon has its own feelings, and Intelligence score, and the same alignment as you.

I would say that 90% of the time, the Eidolon should be controlled by the player. If the GM needs to have a RP moment between you and the Eidolon, then that is a situation where it might be valid. (Or if the GM feels that you are not playing the Eidolon's alignment or whatnot).

An important thing to remember, is the Eidolon is a crucial part of your class skills and features, and I feel it would be unsatisfying for you to not get to play your Eidolon.

Answer (score 16):

Much like summoned creatures, animal companions, bonded mounts, familiars, etc., this is totally up to your DM. All the rules say is that eidolons are treated as summoned creatures, which similarly have ambiguous autonomy.

Typically, DMs will just have PCs control the eidolon directly. The vast majority of gaming groups do this. As with animal companions and the like, there's always the possibility that the DM may feel like the creature would act differently - they have to heed the summoner's commands but in terms of individual initiative and cleverness when say, the summoner is indisposed, it's a grey area.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the rules say that the Eidolon is controlled as a player character. It says it is following the rules of a Summoned creature as per Summoned Monster, but that says they attack and follow the summoner's verbal commands. The extra details of Life Link and so on, none of that indicates control either.

An obvious problem is that Eidlons speak and having a Player have extended conversations with... himself... that's awkwardness that the GM should put a stop to sooner rather than later. GM should at the very least speak for the Eidolon if the Eidlon speaks at all, and the rules on Eidolon actually mean that Eidolon shouldn't obey a summoner who acts out of Alignment.

Sheesh, alignment rules. That can of worms.

One solution is for the PC to invest in the Mount evolution then as long as they are riding the Eidolon they can "guide by knees" which essentially controls all major actions of the mount. Still, GM may say alignment has changed too much and Eidlon goes until they change again.

Of course this question question is limited to whether it is GM or that player, not if yet another player may control Eidolon.

Comment: The last paragraph seems to have exceeded the scope of the question.

Comment: I suppose technically true, as the question was is it the Summoner OR is it the GM rather than leave it so specifically open to any other alternatives though still within the scope of control.