# Eidolon alignment and how it acts under unchained summoner influence

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner, unchained

My player has a chaotic neutral unchained summoner and his eidolon is chaotic evil.
His eidolon has not been fully acting out his alignment and Im wondering how this should be addressed. Yes the summoner has influence over it, but to what extent?

This [form](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2sd8v?Eidolon-Alignment-Restrictions) has some related information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that.

> An eidolon has the same alignment as the summoner that calls it and can speak all of his languages.

Unless you mean the Unchained Summoner, which is a different class, and the eidolon can be a step away.

In that case, the answer is largely contained in [In Pathfinder, does the summoner or the GM control the eidolon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7779/in-pathfinder-does-the-summoner-or-the-gm-control-the-eidolon) and otherwise is like having any other follower, companion, etc. that is or is not the exact same alignment as you.

Comment: You are correct. I made the mistake of not saying it was the unchained summoner.